# Using Jquery function call with Angular 2

Tags: jquery, angular, jquery-plugins

I am trying to use this [convForm](https://github.com/eduardotkoller/convForm) jquery plugin on my Angular 2 application.

I've installed the jquery and the convForm successfully into my project editing the angular.json file.

In the [plugin example](https://github.com/eduardotkoller/convForm/blob/master/index.html), they have callback functions with their html fields under the attribute: **data-callback**.

I don't understand how to use these call back functions within an angular component as the call backs dont call the function with the typescript.

**conv-form.html**

```
<div id="chat" class="conv-form-wrapper">
    <form action="/" method="post" class="hidden" onsubmit="event.preventDefault()">
         <input type="number" data-callback="amount"
              data-conv-question="What is the amount you like ?" name="amount"
              data-pattern="^[0-9]*$">
    </form>
 </div>
```

**conv-form.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
declare let $: any;

@Component({
    selector: 'app-conv-form',
    templateUrl: './conv-form.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./conv-form.component.scss']
})
export class ConvFormComponent implements OnInit {
    ngOnInit() {
          let convForm = $('#chat').convform({ selectInputStyle: 'disable' });
    }

    amount(stateWrapper, ready) {
    if(stateWrapper.current.answer.value.length > 0){
        ready();
    }
  }
}
```

When this question is rendered, I am receiving the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: window[convState.current.input.callback] is not a function
at Object.onInputSubmit
```

How do I call the call back function like the example but in angular?

what is the equivalent to:

```
<script>
    function google(stateWrapper, ready) {
        window.open("https://google.com");
        ready();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery plugin expects a global callback, ie. one one the window object. In the example, the callbacks they declare are simply top level functions in a `<script>` so they will be on the window.
The methods you declare in angular component's class, will be on each component instance, so not avaible globally, ie. the jQuery plugin will not *see* it.

I am really against mixing jQuery and Angular because that always leads to great hacks, but I guess you are going to do it anyway, so here's a possible solition. I don't have any angular+jQuery project lying around, so was not able to test the solution, but I hope it helps.

So you have to put a reference to one of your component instance's method to the window, and so that it will be available globally, but will point to your component instance. See the extended `ngOnInit` below. Also note the `bind` which is needed to be able to use `this` in the `amount` method to access the angular component.

Also be aware that if you display `ConvFormComponent` multiple times on the page, they will intefere, probably only the last one's callback will work. If you need to have multiple ones, you need to introduce a mechanism to make `globalAmountCb` unique for each `ConvFormComponent` instance.

And also, note the `ngOnDestroy` where I removed the callback once the component is being torn down, and you should also tear down / turn off / exit from the jQuery convForm thing.

```html
<div id="chat" class="conv-form-wrapper">
    <form action="/" method="post" class="hidden" onsubmit="event.preventDefault()">
         <input type="number" data-callback="globalAmountCb"
              data-conv-question="What is the amount you like ?" name="amount"
              data-pattern="^[0-9]*$">
    </form>
 </div>
```

```js
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
declare let $: any;
declare window: any;

@Component({
    selector: 'app-conv-form',
    templateUrl: './conv-form.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./conv-form.component.scss']
})
export class ConvFormComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    ngOnInit() {
        // note the `globalAmountCb` name in the template above too
        window.globalAmountCb = this.amount.bind(this).
        let convForm = $('#chat').convform({ selectInputStyle: 'disable' });
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        window.globalAmountCb = undefined;
        // also maybe tear down the `convForm` thing
    }

    amount(stateWrapper, ready) {
    if(stateWrapper.current.answer.value.length > 0){
        ready();
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**: clarification about why and what kind of cleanup might be necessary.

When you navigate away from this page, the angular component class will not be used any more, and will be garbage collected soon, so it doesn't matter if you explicitly remove the `this.convForm` reference.

But only those DOM elements will be removed, of which Angular is aware. Angular is only aware of the DOM which was defined in a component template and was rendered by Angular, but it's not aware of what you added to the DOM via jQuery, so it won't remove those.
If you are lucky, the jQuery plugin only added DOM elements under the angular component, so when the component is removed, the jQuery plugin's DOM elements are also removed.

But it might be the case that the jQuery plugin added something at the top of the DOM tree, maybe outside of the angular application (dialogs and other popovers often work like this), and that won't be removed when the angular component is destroyed.

You have to look into the jQuery plugin if it provides some kind of cleanup mechanism to remove those.

Comment: by tearing down the convForm thing, do you mean use:
this.convForm = undefined

Comment: @helloworld added the response to the answer

Comment: seems to be a destroy function attached to convForm judging from this correspondence :  https://github.com/eduardotkoller/convForm/issues/22